# How to read a string containing a comma and an at sign with textread?

Tags: matlab

My prototype data line looks like this:

```
(1)  11 July   England    0-0    Uruguay   @ Wembley Stadium, London
```

Currently I'm using this:

```
[no,dd,mm,t1,p1,p2,t2,loc]=textread('1966.txt','(%d) %d %s %s %d-%d %s @ %[%s \n]');
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error using dataread
Trouble reading string from file (row 1, field 12) ==> Wembley Stadium, London\n

Error in textread (line 174)
[varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:}); %#ok<REMFF1>
```

So it seems to have trouble with reading a string that contains a comma, or it's the at sign that causes trouble. I read the documentation thoroughly but nowhere does it mention what to do when you have special characters such as @ or if you want to read a string that contains a delimiter even though it I don't want it recognized as a delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
[no,dd,mm,t1,p1,p2,t2,loc] = ...
     textread('1966.txt','(%d) %d %s %s %d-%d %s @ %[^\n]');
```

Comment: Oh what a silly mistake, thank you! Should I delete the question as it doesn't really contribute?

Comment: @PatronBernard In my opinion it is a nice example because it contains many different data types, and therefor it might help others who have problems with reading txt-files.