# Comparing two text files containing numbers in columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, numbers, compare

I have 2 text files (a.txt, b.txt) with some columns of numbers and a header line (one header for each column as shown below). I want to match 2nd col. in a.txt with 1st col. in b.txt and get all the matched rows from b.txt. The numerical values in col.-gr are not repeated either in a.txt or b.txt.

```
a.txt
—————
gc   gr
1    5
3    8
3    4
3    9


b.txt
—————
gr   c1   c2
1    12   32
3    21   23
7    33   12
8    54   45
9    99   65
34   43   76
56   80   24
5    32   80
32   15   23
4    11   31
```

I want matched rows from b.txt exactly like-

```
5    32   80
8    54   45
4    11   31
9    99   65
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What is exactly the problem? Do you know how to read txt-files into matlab? Have you a problem with comparing/finding values? Pls try to show us some work on your own, because right now this looks like a trivial problem which you want others to solve for you

Comment: If your problem is the reading of txt-files check the documentary of `textread()` or `textscan()`. You can also look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232826/how-to-read-a-string-containing-a-comma-and-an-at-sign-with-textread). If the problem is the matching of datapoints. CHeck out `find()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
id = fopen('a.txt','r'); 
A = cell2mat(textscan(id,'%d %d','headerlines',1));
fclose(id);
id = fopen('b.txt','r'); 
B = cell2mat(textscan(id,'%d %d %d','headerlines',1));
fclose(id);

out_ = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)(B(find(A(i,2) == B(:,1),1,'first'),:)),1:size(A,1),'uni',0)');
```